# Реализация поиска по кнопкам в Activity (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, search, scrollview

В активити присутствует компонент SearchView и ScrollView с кнопками. Каким образом можно реализовать по ним поиск и, если совпадений нет, отсеивание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал с помощью массива кнопок. Получал текст с каждой и сравнивал строку пользователя и текст. Если совпадений не найдено - кнопки выключал)

Comment: Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой же проблемой, в разработке андроид приложений я новенький, не могли бы вы поделиться этим кусочком кода?